# Leaflet markercluster plugin doesn't display locations correctly

Tags: leaflet

```
let sampling_location_layer=L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
showCoverageOnHover: false,
zoomToBoundsOnClick: true
});

fetch(url+sql)
  .then(function(response){
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
      var sampling_layer = L.geoJson(data)
      markers.addLayer(sampling_layer)
      war_site_layer.addLayer(markers)
        //Create a time slider   
      var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
            position: "topright",
            layer: sampling_layer,
            timeAttribute: 'controle_date'`enter code here`
```

My code is pretty simple here, just trying out the clustermarker function. However, it seems like the locations are totally off as shown in the screenshot here. The markers aren't in their correct locations specified by its lat and lon (the location can be displayed correctly when clustermarker is not used).[image]

Comment: Want to clarify my question a bit: the markers expanded from the cluster group is not at its original location. I have seem several examples like this. Does clustermarker just do that?

Comment: To clarify your question please use the [edit] button beneath it to revise it.

Comment: Yes, for clustered markers spiderify means just that. You can use `spiderfyShapePositions` option to modify algorithm that creates/defines spiderified markers positions.